# How to solve for $\theta$ in an expression involving linear and $\sin$ terms

Tags: geometry

While trying to solve a spatial geometry problem, I came across the expression:
$$156θ-36\sin\theta=554.8$$
And I have no idea where to even begin.

Comment: You could begin by graphing expression to find an approximate value for $\theta$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a nice way to find an exact expression to solve this (possibly if you get really fancy with the Lambert W function, which still isn't really much of a solution). However, you can find increasingly accurate solutions via numerical methods such as [Newton-Raphson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method).

Comment: The possibility of a Lambert-W solution to equations like this has occurred to me in the past, but I've failed every attempt to make it work. If this can be done I'd very much like to see it.

Comment: Well, I'm not that far into math yet, so I did it the rudimentary way , trying with several different angles until I found one that was "close enough".

Comment: Newton's method is really just an extension of that kind of guessing-and-checking. Another method is the bisection method - if you know there's a solution between x1 and x2, try their average. Then work out whether the solution is between x1 and the average or the average and x2, and redefine x1 and x2 based on that, and repeat. Newton usually converges faster if the function is behaving nicely in the region, but bisection works for any continuous function.

Answer (score 1):

Equations in which are present polynomial terms and trigonometric functions do not shaow analytical solutions and only numerical methods could be used.

For your specific case, since $-1 \leq \sin(\theta) \leq 1$, you can easily detect that the solution is between the solutions of $$156 \theta-36=554.8$$ $$156\theta+36=554.8$$  that is to say $$3.32564 \lt \theta \lt 3.78718$$

If you just need an approximate solution, you could develop the equation as a Taylor expansion built at $\theta =\pi$ and get $$156\theta-36\sin(\theta)-554.8 \approx \left(156 \pi -\frac{2774}{5}\right)+192 (\theta -\pi )+O\left((\theta -\pi
   )^2\right)$$ and get $$\theta =\frac{1387+90 \pi}{480} \approx 3.47863$$

If you need an accurate solution, use Newton method which, starting from a *reasonable* guess $\theta_0$, will update it according to $$\theta_{n+1}=\theta_{n}-\frac{f(\theta_{n})}{f'(\theta_{n})}$$ For your case $$f(\theta)=156\theta-36\sin(\theta)-554.8$$ $$f'(\theta)=156-36\cos(\theta)$$ Let us be lazy and start using $\theta_0=\pi$; so, the following iterates are generated : $3.47863$, $3.47983$ which is the solution for six significant figures.

Just to show how fast this scheme converges, let me give you the iterates with $25$ decimal figures up to solution

> $3.478631955881419565545079$
>
> $3.479834304497599014491005$
>
> $3.479834349849334038884468$
>
> $3.479834349849334103555807$

Answer (score 0):

You could express $\sin \theta$ as its Taylor series and then get an approximate answer (you will have a 5th/7th power to solve depending on how accurate you go.)